# Foursquare OAuthV2 for iOS

Tags: ios, oauth, callback, foursquare

I am a newbie here and am trying to use the Foursquare API to build a mobile application. Most of my functionality is client side and I do not want to host my application but the OAuth process requires me to provide an application URL and a callback URL. Any ideas on whether I can get around this requirement? Can I provide dummy URLs?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a dummy URL and sniff the key off of the path (see: https://github.com/anoopr/core-data-talk/blob/master/example/Classes/FoursquareAuthViewController.m).

Alternatively, I believe you can specify an iOS custom URL scheme that you application then handles appropriately.

Comment: The sample link you gave is great! Thanks @akdotcom!!